# unarchiving NSAttributedString in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I tried archiving an NSAttributedString in Mac OSX 10.7 and then tried to unarchive it in iOS 4..  I get an error:

> cannot decode object of class (NSParagraphStyle)

I see that there's no NSParagraphStyle in iOS. So my question is, is there a workaround or is it not possible to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method `setClass:forClassName` and provide a class of your own to use for `NSParagraphStyle`. That class would have to implement `initWithCoder:` and you could either ignore it or try to replicate `NSParagraphStyle` with what's available on iOS (`CTParagraphStyle` which is quite difficult to work with).

Comment: I had to do the same for NSFont and it did worked without actually doing nothing... But when I added a picture it asked for NSTextStorage. I tried to provide a class for it, but it requires actually implementing it...